# Hide some topics when launching a node?

Tags: ros, node, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some nodes I launch publish topics I never intend to use, and they just clutter up the namespace.  Is there a way to prevent a node from publishing a topic at launch time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217418/hide-some-topics-when-launching-a-node?/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to prevent a node from publishing a topic at launch time?

Other than editing the source of the node in question?

No.

---

If you are worried about collisions and / or multiple nodes publishing to the same topic, and you'd like to avoid that, you could make use of [remapping or namespacing](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0